# How to implement such design in react native

Tags: react-native

I have to implement such a design in my project. I have no idea how to implement such a design.

Are there any packages available for implementing such a design?

I am using the **FlatList** component for rendering list items.

I am doing the project in **react-native**

[image]

**Working Environment:-**

```
react-native: 0.64.1
```

Comment: How to implement *yourself*; I believe it's a lot of work and I'm not sure how to make it. But if you want to delegate to a package, I think you're looking for the keyword "masonry"

Answer (score 1):

Try using [react-native-masonry-list](https://github.com/hyochan/react-native-masonry-list)

```
<MasonryList
  data={filteredItems}
  keyExtractor={(item, index): string => index.toString()}
  numColumns={2}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  renderItem={({item}) => <CardItem />}
  refreshing={isLoadingNext}
  onRefresh={() => refetch({first: ITEM_CNT})}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
  onEndReached={() => loadNext(ITEM_CNT)}
/>
```

For custom implementation, this [article](https://medium.com/dooboolab/react-native-masonry-list-a5365647f2c1) would help you

Answer (score 0):

Just use flatliat like below:
But be aware of the last item you should add flex:1/2

```
<FlatList 
  data={data}
  numColumns={2}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id }
  renderItem={(item) => <Card/>/> }
/>
```